# Getting file with today date from SFTP

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel, date, sftp

How would you go about getting a file from a SFTP server if the file has today date in the name of file?

I know the `mget` and `get` command is used to pull the file over, but I can't seem to find anything on pulling a file if it has a certain timestamp on it. I'm trying to write a `bash` script to pull this file down every morning but the name of the file changes everyday.

Example of the file I am trying to get pulled down from a sftp:

```
get arc.20201005.*
```

What I have tried:

```
get arc.$(date +%Y%m%d).*
get arc.(date +%Y%m%d).*
```

Comment: Does it have to be `sftp` or could you use `scp`?

Comment: Does your example filename of `arc.20201005.*` work as expected? Have you tried: `get arc.$(date +%Y%m%d).\*` ? I'm wondering if your local shell is expanding the *.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer. Since SFTP doesn't allow variables and has limited commands itself. I instead did the following.

```
#Set Variables

date=(date +%Y%m%d)

echo -e "mget /directorypath/arc.$date.*" | sftp username@IPaddress
```

The -e in the echo command is key to this working since it enables interpretation of backslash escapes.